# How can I disable an audio HDMI device?

Tags: sound, hdmi

powertop reports that Intel CougarPoint HDMI is 100% active and there are reports that this device consumes a lot of power. If that is so, I would like to disable it as I never use it. Is there a way I can disable it?

I am using Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: You can use Gnome extension "Quick Settings Audio Devices Hider" to hide/show any audio devices you like.

Answer (score 57):

I had the same issue when I updated to Ubuntu 19.10.

1. Open **PulseAudio Volume Control**. I believe it's already installed by default.
2. Click the **Configuration** tab.
3. Find your HDMI device and set the Profile to **Off**.

[image: PulseAudio Volume Control screenshot]

If it's not install, you can install the PulseAudio control panel using:

```
sudo apt install pavucontrol
```

Comment: This solution is exactly what i needed and still works in 19.10 as of writing. (it isn't installed by default in 19.10)

Comment: This is working for Ubuntu 20 by the way. I had system audio sent to analog stereo (aux headphones) but Firefox kept playing sound through my HDMI display speakers. Thank you!

Comment: it keeps enabling itself again after some time. super annoying

Comment: Any solution to re-enabling issue? I'm using Ubuntu 20.04..

Comment: Found the solution for re-enabling. Open `/etc/pulse/default.pa` and comment out `load-module module-switch-on-port-available` line. Save file. Reload pulseaudio using `pulseaudio -k`.

Comment: @charith.arumapperuma won't that prevent the system from responding to any device which is connected or disconnected? From https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#module-switch-on-port-available
"module-switch-on-port-available: Since 2.0. Automatically switches the card profile and/or device port when a port changes its availablility status. In practice this happens when plugging in or out something to/from a 3.5mm connector (not on USB sound cards, though, since they don't support jack detection) or a HDMI connector."

Comment: This was the solution I was looking for! I was able to select the laptop sound card as the default fallback device!!! On Linux Mint 20.10 I was able to use the software manger to install `Pavucontrol`

Answer (score 5):

1. Click on the speaker icon, top right. Choose 'Sound Settings...'
2. Click on the Hardware tab
3. Select the HDMI device and choose 'Off' from the pull-down menu.

[image]

Comment: The _Hardware_ tab seems to have disappeared in newer versions of Ubuntu (I'm using 13.10 and don't see it.)

Comment: Yea, what's up with that?

Comment: Referring to GUI to solve these issues isn't a good idea, guis change. Radically and are contingent on config.

Answer (score 4):

#### As per other answer:

*Off* mode in pavucontrol lives it's own life and is not persistent.

Using `load-module module-switch-on-port-available` in `/etc/pulse/default.pa` does not look like a desired solution.

---

#### Another approach:

- Sudo Edit: `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`
- Add: `blacklist snd_hda_codec_hdmi`
- Run: `pulseaudio -k` to restart pulseaudio.

---

Downside: even with it blacklisted it re-appear if it is on a device that is attached after boot. E.g: I have 6 monitors where one have HDMI-audio. If I de-activate the HDMI monitor and then activate it the HDMI-audio for it is *activated*. Have not investigate why.

Comment: How you get this? `snd_hda_codec_hdmi` i'm interested in disable a digital output, not hdmi

Comment: @ArnoldRoa IIRC from `lsmod`. Not sure what you have to look for for digital output (SPDIF?).

Answer (score -2):

To disable the audio device (not just mute) run in terminal

```
sudo alsa force-unload
```

---

`alsa` options are

```
unload|reload|force-unload|force-reload|suspend|resume
```

In case you require the audio device at a later stage.

Comment: This disables ALL devices. I want to disable just one.

Comment: it's actually a somewhat useful answer regardless