# Vmware Player disconnected my soundcard, how can I re-connect it?

Tags: sound, vmware, soundcard

When connecting the sound-card to the guest OS on Vmware Player, it notified me it would disconnect it from the host (ubuntu) and connect it to the guest.

[image]

I disconnected the soundcard from the guest, and exit vmware player, yet my laptop internal sound is not working. I am assuming it is still disconnected, how can I re-connected or find what is causing the problem? Or at lest reset my audio settings?

[image]

Note: My laptop seems to have two devices, one for headphones/speaker and one for the internal sound, when I choose Internal Audio Analog Stereo and plug my headphones, sound works...

Answer (score 1):

I was able to sort out intermittent sound issues by disabling the HDMI output since I wasn't using it anyway. I posted an answer [here with a how-to](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78780/how-can-i-disable-an-audio-hdmi-device). If this works, then the problem wasn't with VMware, but an issue where Ubuntu prioritises HDMI over Analog (which was my problem).

If this solves the problem for you then maybe this should be edited or merged with the other question.