# Mic "disables" after restart

Tags: sound, multimedia, microphone

I have configurated the front mic as imput in sound settings, and it works fine, but after I restart the PC (no always the first time, but sooner or later it happens) the PC doesn't capture anything from the front mic, that is still selected and not mute. To make it work again I have to select other imput device and then select the front mic again.

This is annoying, is there some way to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: I had a similar problem I solved by disabling unnecessary hardware in sound options, posted as an answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/78780/how-can-i-disable-an-audio-hdmi-device/85076#85076). Can you try this and see if it helps?

Comment: @TomBrossman My sound options only shows one hardware device: Internal audio.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)