# Sound settings revert to wrong hardware profile after screen saver

Tags: sound, screensaver

I face a problem since about a month ago. I have a TV connected to my PC with HDMI but audio goes to my stereo (analog). The setup works great but each time the I return from the screen saver, the sound settings revert to a HDMI output only profile. I need the "Analog stereo duplex" setting.

On Oneiric I access this setting: Sound Settings->Hardware (tab) -> Profile:

Anybody know how to keep it from changing or why it happens? It started occurring mid March.

Comment: Can you try my answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/85076/12864) and see if this fixes it? The answer is geared for someone not using HDMI at all, and I'm curious if you still get video (and solve the problem).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I already upgraded to 12.04 and it solved the problem. The sound settings seem different in 12.04, so unfortunately I cannot test it anymore.

Comment: Same issue with Ubuntu 11.10. After screensaver sound is switched to HDMI.