# How to set priority for Sound Output Devices in Gnome

Tags: gnome, sound, 19.10, settings

Using Ubuntu 19.10 I have 3 output devices in Settings -> Sound -> Output-Device:

- HDMI (monitor)
- S/PDIF (onboard)
- Headphone (onboard)

AMD 2400G, Asus PRIME B450M-A

I need this priority:

1. Headphones
2. HDMI
3. S/PDIF (unused)

So it should switch to headphones if plugged in, otherwise HDMI.

Now it starts with HDMI, no matter if headphones is plugged in. When I select headphone, and later unplug headphone, it falls back to S/PDIF which is not used at all.

Shouldn't the GUI offer a draggable list to order my preferences? I kinda like the simplicity of Gnome GUI, but sometimes it's too minimal.

How do I set priority?

Comment: I know it will probably not help you, but KDE does support it - you just reorder devices in the list https://i.imgur.com/pZbVt.png

Comment: I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you would set priority, but there is a way to shut off the S/PDIF. Open Pulse Audio Volume Control and turn off S/PDIF. It should disappear from the Volume Settings list. (found here - https://askubuntu.com/a/1186737/150363)

As for the headphones bit, you may still have to manually choose them, but when you unplug (if you followed the above), it should go back to HDMI.

Comment: Thx, but doesn't help. AFAICS it is enabled at the moment I plug-in a headphone again. Onboard sound with SPDIF and analog out.