# How do you set the default speaker?

Tags: sound, speakers

For some reason my USB headphone stand is registered as a speaker by Ubuntu. For some reason, Ubuntu prefers to use it over my actual speakers. I can change it to the proper speaker, but it's somewhat annoying to do that whenever I start my computer. Is it possible to teach Ubuntu which one should be used as the default speaker?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1227403/how-to-set-priority-for-sound-output-devices-in-gnome  KDE was suggested to reorder the sound device priorities.  Also, see https://wolfgang-ziegler.com/blog/prevent-changing-of-default-ubuntu-sound-device

Comment: The second link is super useful, but somehow pactl doesn't find my speakers. The funny thing is, the speakers actually do work and I can set them in the system settings UI thingy. But pactl doesn't list them...