# Audio does not work after upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

My audio does not work anymore after the upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04.
This is my output of `inxi -SMA`:

```
System:
  Host: costanza Kernel: 5.4.0-28-generic x86_64 bits: 64 
  Desktop: Gnome 3.36.1 Distro: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:
  Type: Desktop Mobo: ASRock model: B150M-ITX 
  serial: <superuser/root required> UEFI: American Megatrends v: P7.00 
  date: 10/27/2016 
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel 100 Series/C230 Series Family HD Audio 
  driver: snd_hda_intel 
  Device-2: NVIDIA GP104 High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-28-generic
```

This is what I have tried until now:

1. `sudo alsa force-reload`

   => Did not work. This also kills blender 2.80 if I have it open
2. I have purged and reinstalled alsa and pulseaudio with

   ```
   sudo apt remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio` and `sudo apt install alsa-base pulseaudio
   ```

   => Did not work.
3. I have installed `pavucontrol` => Did not work.
4. I have disabled the GP104 High Definition Audio control option in the pulseaudio volume control GUI, leaving just "Built-in audio" active, as explained [here at AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78780/how-can-i-disable-an-audio-hdmi-device), and then I have restarted alsa with `alsa force-reload`. This seems to work temporarily, but after a while, the audio disappears again.

Comment: Regarding point 4, it works if blender is not open. Probably related to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1236160/blender-interferes-with-youtube-on-ubuntu-20-04 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1235615/ubuntu-20-04-mozilla-wont-play-youtube-video-if-i-open-blender-first