# Ubuntu 20.04 Mozilla won't play youtube video if I open Blender first

Tags: firefox, youtube

I am very new at ubuntu, I just installed it,

when I open blender program first, then opening youtube, the video won't play, but if I close blender the video will play, then there is no issue if I open another tab of youtube,

however, if I close both program and start the exact same way by open blender first then youtube, issue will pop up again, any ideas what I am doing wrong?

sorry before, and thank you

edit: is Fixed in the newer release of blender-snap https://developer.blender.org/T72920

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: This was fixed in Blender in https://developer.blender.org/T72920